# Is it possible to adjust the top position based on window size in CSS?

Tags: html, css

```css
#imgmenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

#icon img {
  position: relative;
  top: 70%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 3%;
  height: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgmenu">
  <div id="icon">
    <img src="crow.png" class="image" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Left works as intended - when the window is expanded or compressed horizontally, the x-position adjusts accordingly, but the y-position seems to be fixed and doesn't adjust when the window size is changed vertically.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have declared the img as position relative. If I'm not mistaken, position relative should be used to an element with fixed position and would be the basis for positioning an absolute element.

I think what you really meant to code is this one:

```
#imgmenu {
    position: relative;
    top: 0%; 
    left: 0%; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;  
}

#icon img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 3%;
    height: 3%; 
}
```

Comment: This worked after I changed absolute to fixed. Thank you so much!